# Is the use of "till" natural here?

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

I am writing about a book. So what should I use "till/to"?

> This book is so gripping, that it keeps you ensnared **till** the last word.
>
> This book is so gripping, that it keeps you ensnared **to** the last word.

I think that "till" should be used with a period of time and thus it doesn't sound natural here. What do you think? Does it sound natural? If yes, then why? And could you explain it to me with a few examples as well?

Comment: So what do you think should be used @Lambie? "End", "drop" are actually related to a time period... But I guess "till the last word" isn't.. But I don't know, that's why is asked... So what should be used here : "till" or "to"?

Comment: But will "till" or even "until" sound natural in this context, @Lambie? It is more about "should it be "till" or "to"?

Comment: Will "to" sound natural? And I asked why does "till" sound natural there? Is it related to a time "period" as well? @Lambie?

Comment: I answered your question and you keep repeating it. Dictionary examples answer this question. Please show research you have done. So I removed my comments. [Does "to" sound natural? not will]